# Velocity.js fadeIn/fadeOut on div with fixed/absolute element buggy in IE 10

Tags: html, css-position, css-animations, velocity.js

I'm trying to animate(fade in/out) a div containing an element that is  fixed/absolute position, it work well in chrome BUT when i tested it on IE10/Edge, it has some undesirable effects like delay or lag (ie the back button at the bottom of the page is not fading together with the other element within the same div), was wondering anyone have any workaround on this?

```js
$(function() {

  var $first = $('.first'),
    $second = $('.second');

  $second.velocity('fadeOut', 'fast');

  $first.on('click', function(e) {
    $first.velocity('fadeOut', 'slow', function() {
      $second.velocity('fadeIn', 'slow');
    })
  });

  $second.on('click', function(e) {
    $second.velocity('fadeOut', 'slow', function() {
      $first.velocity('fadeIn', 'slow');
    })
  });

});
```

```css
.back-button {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://julian.com/research/velocity/build/jquery.velocity.min.js"></script>

<div class="first">
  <button>
    Page
  </button>
  <button>
    One
  </button>
  <button class="back-button">
    Back Button
  </button>
</div>

<div class="second">
  <button>
    Page
  </button>
  <button>
    Two
  </button>
  <button class="back-button">
    Back Button
  </button>
</div>
```

[Sample recreation of my issue can be seen in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z05ojckg/)